# OOP best practice - validating user input within the property setter?

Tags: oop

I'm new to OOP (and PHP) and I'm struggling with what is considered best practice or at least a common approach to validating user input.

At the moment I'm doing this within the property setter of my object and although I understand this to be the perfect place for business logic, it feels a little strange putting input sanitization code there (for instance stripping all non numeric characters from an ID field).

Although I can put this type of input sanitization into the front end scripts, the sanitization code can be specific to that property, so this is my counter argument that it should be within the object setter?

Confused... Looking for some advice please.

Comment: Methods should perform a single task. A setter should "set" data. If you want a place to validate data, might be best to put it as a step before saving data.

Comment: OK, but doesn't that leave the potential for the object to be in an invalid state? I.e. you could skip the validation step?

Comment: Not if you make a validation step mandatory as part of the save process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Validating' the setter's parameter, throwing an exception on an invalid argument sounds reasonable.

'Sanitising' or otherwise conforming to the methods precondition(s) should be the responsibility of the caller.

Changing user input is not usually a good idea. Letting the user know what they must enter and informing them of errors is a more pragmatic approach.

Validation often needs to occur in several places, a validation library would help by giving a model for you to reuse validation logic.

Comment: Thanks, between your response and Robbie's above, this sounds a far better approach.